# How do I write a Graql query that looks for for an attribute between two dates?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have the following question I want to ask in Graql: "Give me every person who was born between June 1999 and September 1999"

I have tried writing it like this but I don't think this is right?

```
match
$p isa person, has age $a; 
{$a contains "June";} or {$a contains "September"};
$a contains "1999"; get;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a semicolon after "September"!